# Convert Powershell command to CMD

Tags: powershell

I have the following *PowerShell command I'd like to run*:

```
Get-AppxPackage -allusers *mspaint* | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml”}
```

Then I have an example of a cmd.exe line executing PowerShell:

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command "Get-AppxPackage -allusers *messaging* | Remove-AppxPackage"
```

I would like some help to convert the PowerShell line above to a cmd.exe line version.

Comment: what do you mean by "cmd line version"?

Comment: cmd line as in the old DOS box (batch file).... command line

Comment: you likely ought to add that info to your Question. [*grin*] as it stands, your post is  ... vague to the point of being nearly incomprehensible. ///// the Answer posted by `Joost` covers the basic idea for running PoSH code from a BAT file - call `Powershell.exe` with the correct parameters. [*grin*]

Comment: Trick question.  mspaint is not an appxpackage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works (without the `-whatif`), although I'm not sure why you would want to do it.  You can even leave off the last double-quote.  Cmd only understands double-quotes to escape the pipe.

```
powershell "Get-AppxPackage -allusers microsoft.mspaint | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register ($_.InstallLocation + '\AppXManifest.xml') -whatif }"
```

Answer (score 0):

This Code works

powershell "Get-AppxPackage -allusers *mspaint* | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register ($_.InstallLocation + '\AppXManifest.xml')}"

Thank you for your help guys!

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick:

```
powershell.exe -Command "& {Get-AppxPackage -allusers mspaint | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register `"$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml`"}}"
```

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/About/about_PowerShell_exe?view=powershell-5.1#-command

Comment: thank you... I did try this... but im getting a - Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndCurlyBrace

Comment: I think it's to do with the double quotes, which I may have incorrectly escaped.  Can you try without the backticks: `powershell.exe -Command "& {Get-AppxPackage -allusers mspaint | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}}"`

Comment: Backslash seems to work.  There's an error in the question.  The app is called microsoft.mspaint.

Comment: **Sorry, it should be**  mspaint should have the astrix on it... as this site uses them it stripped them LOL

Comment: powershell.exe -Command "& {Get-AppxPackage -allusers mspaint | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}}"  - doesnt work for me, it runs but nothing happens